# How to fetch rows based on selected counts of each gender?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to write a query where we have a **users** table including name, age gender, dob etc.
I need to fetch data on the bases of given counts of each gender.

For ex:- 20 Male and 20 Female
Query:

```
mysql> select name, email,  gender from users;
+--------------+-------------------------+--------+
| name         | email                   | gender |
+--------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Mangal       | test444@yopmail.com     | M      |
| Manish Verma | mannverma@yopmail.com   | M      |
| Mangal       | mangal@yopmail.com      | M      |
| Sandeep      | sandeep@yopmail.com     | F      |
| Gourav       | gouerav@yopmail.com     | M      |
| Gourav       | 22222@yopmail.com       | F      |
| Dddddd       | ddddd@yopmail.com       | M      |
| Testapp      | testapp@yopmail.com     | F      |
| Sssss        | suji@yopmail.com        | M      |
| Mangal       | mangaltest@yopmail.com  | M      |
| Ajayww       | aju@yopmail.com         | F      |
| Ajayww       | ajunew@yopmail.com      | M      |
| Anila        | anil@yopmail.com        | M      |
| Mangal       | mangal@gmail.com        | F      |
| Kok          | kok@yopmail.com         | F      |
| Sdsad        | opop@yopmail.com        | F      |
| Abc          | abc@abc.com             | F      |
| Chandu       | chandu@yopmail.com      | M      |
| Ankit        | ankit22@gmail.com       | M      |
| Najkia       | aku@yopmail.com         | M      |
+--------------+-------------------------+--------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please help.

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: Can you show us a query you have tried already?

Comment: Try `group by gender` and `count` in your query

Comment: @fa06 Please take a look at sample data i have added.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender='m' limit 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM users WHERE gender='f' limit 5)
```

In the place of 5 you use your own number which you want to fetch.

Important point to remembered when using union. both the subqueries should have the same column index.

Edit: based on the understanding from the comments.

Comment: i don't need group count of gender. I need to select specific counts of genders like 5 male and 5 female.

Comment: @ManishVerma Cool. then you will have to use UNION in your query. two queries each to fetch each gender with LIMIT and combine both the queries with union

Comment: oh yes. You are right i just forgot about unions. Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: The advice regarding unions should be included in the answer.  (or just use Tim's answer -- he seldom makes mistakes)

Comment: @mickmackusa Except for occasionally answering bad duplicate questions :-P